# Line of business application settings

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, settings, line-of-business-app

I am developing a winrt lob application that uses some Sharepoint Lists. Some settings (like sharepoint address or lists names) have to be common for all the user within the same company.

I would like to know if there is a way to set this parameter before the deployment of the apps, so the users don't have to do it because they probably don't even know about sharepoint configuration

Comment: I assume that will be a sideloaded app?

Comment: In this case yes. I've seen that maybe i can use Intune but it's going to be very expensive

Answer (score 0):

You should use Settings charm for your app with default values in textbox/dropdown to configure anything